# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android and starting to develop this app I got these error in Logcat, probably related to the theme applied or maybe to the device I used for testing (API 23). I found similar error in web but I can't understand the reason.

Here is the Logcat:

```
03-12 16:58:54.453 14745-14745/? E/Zygote: v2
03-12 16:58:55.948 14745-14745/thezone.passwordlocker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: thezone.passwordlocker, PID: 14745
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{thezone.passwordlocker/thezone.passwordlocker.SignupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                            at thezone.passwordlocker.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:25)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                            at thezone.passwordlocker.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:25) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/thezone.passwordlocker-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/thezone.passwordlocker-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                            at thezone.passwordlocker.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:25) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 26 more
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

The Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="thezone.passwordlocker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".LinkedActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The .java main activity:

```
package thezone.passwordlocker;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";

   EditText _nameText;
   EditText _emailText;
   EditText _passwordText;
   Button _signupButton;
   TextView _loginLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signup();
            }
        });

        _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void signup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

        if (!validate()) {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;
        }

        _signupButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
                        // depending on success
                        onSignupSuccess();
                        // onSignupFailed();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);
    }


    public void onSignupSuccess() {
        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();
    }

    public void onSignupFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
            _nameText.setError("at least 3 characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _nameText.setError(null);
        }

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

The main activity layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@mipmap/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!--  Name Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:hint="Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Create Account"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member? Login"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Gradle dependecies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "thezone.passwordlocker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Design Support Library dependency

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`

Your layout uses a widget from the library : `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

Comment: Initializing Button and TextView were missing too. Now it's ok.